# is there a way to force a computer into sleep mode at certain times?

Tags: windows, sleep, power-management, group-policy

for example, to save electricity.  Could you make a domain policy that makes a pc go to sleep between the hours of 9 pm and 6 am.  You can always turn it back on.  It just goes to sleep unless it's being used or it gets woke up.

Thank you.

EDIT:  Sorry, they are all Windows machines.  XP, Vista, and Windows 7, but mostly XP Pro.  Lots of machines.

Comment: Which OS?  Are you only interested in doing this to one or two systems, or a whole bunch of them?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using Windows, here is a command line that will send the PC to sleep

```
rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

you could either create a batch file to remotely execute this command on all pc at a certain time using psexec, and then another batch file to send a wol command out when you want them woken up.

Alternatively you could schedule these two functions manually on each machine

Comment: It's saying task already exists even if it doesn't.

Comment: *** Warning, this command caused my machine to Hibernate rather than sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS.  For XP, Energy Star has something called EZ GPO to manage power.  I believe Vista and Windows 7  have GPOs for this.

[EnergyStar](http://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?c=power_mgt.pr_pm_ez_gpo)