# Force computer to sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep

I plays songs and I want to force the computer to sleep after 15 minutes. If I'm playing a song the default sleep when Idle after `x` minutes does not work. Is it possible to force the computer to sleep, even if not idle?

PS: I Already tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/121386/133969).

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd, and type `shutdown -s -f -t 900`
`-s` means shutdown, `-f` means force shutdown, `-t` means timer, and `900` means 900 seconds

To cancel the shutdown, type `shutdown -a` (`-a` means abort shutdown)

Comment: The question was about putting to sleep, not shutting down.